# Firebase install

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm new to coding and programming swift
I've tried to install  2 firebase pods FirebaseAuth and FirebaseFirestore with terminal on my current
project but terminal shows me some errors and it won't install pods
errors are :
1-pod install fails with json error on Mac OS X 10.15
2-Invalid Podfile: pod install fails with use_native_modules!
3-pod search
my pod file content is

```
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Flash Chat iOS13' do

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Flash Chat iOS13
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Did you search for this?

Comment: You may try this: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9260

Comment: Which folder you write "pod install" at terminal?

Comment: Please copy and paste your entire podfile into the question. Also, ensure you completely quit XCode. Then navigate in terminal the the project folder and verify you're in the correct directory (folder) by typing *LS* into terminal (either upper or lower case) and observe the output as it should be three items; your project name (*Flash Chat iOS13.xcodeproj*) a file called *podfile* and your project. Then type *pod install* into terminal. Report back with the results

Answer (score 0):

```
 # Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

 # Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
 # For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore.
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

 # then type the following command
   pod install
```